# Amazon's prices are significantly less that Australian online-shops

Tags: australia

I am not in Sydney right now, but when I compare the price of some stuffs (laptop for example) the prices on Amazon.com (product price+shipping cost) are far less than the price of exactly the same product on Australian online shopping web sites. This seems odd.

Can you please provide some guideline regarding online shopping in Australia?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this seems like thinly veiled spam.

Comment: Australian prices are high.

Comment: Make sure you are not comparing US dollars with Australian dollars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe when Amazon.com was visited the prices were displayed in United States Dollars. USD is currently significantly more expensive than Australian Dollars.

You can compare the prices on the Australian Amazon (amazon.com.au) to have a better comparison with the local stores.

Answer (score 3):

Yup, that's the famous Australia Tax: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Australia_Tax

Basically, because it's a small, wealthy and largely captive market, with expensive labour and transport costs, buying *anything* in Australia is generally expensive.

And yes, online shopping is one common way around this, especially since many merchants have free shipping and there is no duty or GST on most goods under $1000 (although this may change in 2017).  The savings aren't as good as they used to be thanks to the current weak Australian dollar, but buying direct from China via eBay or Aliexpress can still provide incredible bargains though.

Also note that Amazon.com.au sells virtual goods only, you'll need to use Amazon.com for physical products.

Comment: How big are the savings if you factor in all applicable taxes and duties?

Comment: @Gala How long is a piece of string? But there are no duties/GST for purchases under $1000.

Comment: Why do you always need to be so argumentative? It's just a suggestion to improve your answer further (which I already upvoted incidentally) and taxes are neither unknowable nor irrelevant. When importing stuff from the US to the EU, it basically cancels the difference. And the allowance for goods shipped from abroad (as opposed to things you carry with you) is very low. It's interesting to know whether that's the case for Australia or not (I didn't know about the $1000 threshold for example).

Comment: @Gala Sorry, but I just don't think there's a sensible way to summarise.  Some goods are less than half price, others there's barely any difference. My main driver for shopping online is the variety though, there are many things you can't buy locally at all. (Random examples: some brands of jeans/khakis in my unusual size, Lego kids watches, most Nexus 5x accessories...)

Comment: But I've added in the note about tax/duty or lack thereof.

Comment: Wasn't obvious to me as it does not line up with my experience in other parts of the world where differences are often sufficiently predictable to be summarized reasonably easily. Explaining that the first time around might have been more effective than being cute...